# 'in control of' and 'in the control of' are different?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Q1. My dictionary says that "The city **is in *the* control of** enemy force" means "The city is controlled by enemy force." Then, "The situation **is in *the* control of** the police." means "The situation is controlled by the police"?

Q2. What about this?
"The police **is in *the* control of** the situation" means "The police is controlled by the situation"? While "The police **is in control of** the situation" means "The situation is controlled by the police"?

Q3. I mean "**be in ***the*** control of** ~" and "**be in control of** ~" are different meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which dictionary are you using?

The correct sentence would be:

> The police are in control of the situation.

This means that the police are doing the action of controlling or creating a sense of control and the object of that action is the situation. You wouldn't normally use the passive voice for such a sentence.

You only use in "the control of" something when it refers to the operation or proper regulation of something.

Example:

> Scientists have invented a new device that allows patients to avoid
> disruptions in the control of their blood sugar.

Comment: "The police **are** in control", surely.

Comment: @Stangdon: British English: The police *are* in control. American English: The police *is* in control. I am Canadian (we use a bit of a mix). https://editorsmanual.com/articles/collective-nouns-singular-or-plural/

Comment: @Yuri.teacher.English  I **am** a native US English speaker, born and raised, and I would never say "The police is..."  You'll notice that on that page you link to, it specifically says that *police* is always plural.

Comment: That is true... An oversight on my part.